# CUDA C++ : Is something special about the number 64?

Tags: c++, cuda, multidimensional-array, pitch

I'm experiencing some pathological behavior with a numerical integrator that I've programmed in C++ and CUDA to operate on my GPU.  My integrator is using a fixed step size at the moment, and the moment I set the number of points (numpoints) to integrate to 65 (making the step size go to 1/65 and the width of a 2D array in which I store the calculated data to be 65), my integrator doesn't work and it seems like a function somewhere is returning zero.  Is there something wrong with 2D arrays that are larger than 64 doubles wide?

I've tried implementing the macro that Talonmies wrote in [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) Apparently, something is going wrong in my kernel and with the copying of data calculated by the kernel back to the host.  "GPU assert: invalid argument."  I'm not sure how to interpret these errors or where to proceed from here.

My suspicion is that it has either something to do with the width of the 2D array being larger than 64 or the pitch and how I store things in a 2D array on the device.  Does the following code correctly fill in a column of a 2D array?

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>                      //display 2 decimal places
using namespace std;

__global__ void rkf5(double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*, size_t, double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void calcK(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k1(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k2(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k3(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k4(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k5(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void k6(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void arrAdd(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void arrMult(double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void arrInit(double*, double);
__device__ void setup(double , double*, double*, double*, double*, int*);
__device__ double flux(int, double*) ;
__global__ void storeConcs(double*, size_t, double*, int);
__global__ void takeFourthOrderStep(double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*);
__global__ void takeFifthOrderStep(double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*);

//Error checking that I don't understand yet.
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

//Main program.
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    //std::cout << std::fixed;          //display 2 decimal places
    //std::cout << std::setprecision(16);   //display 2 decimal places
    const int maxlength = 1;            //Number of discrete concentrations we are tracking.
    double concs[maxlength];            //Meant to store the current concentrations 
    double temp[maxlength];             //Used as a bin to store products of Butcher's tableau and k values.
    double tempsum[maxlength];          //Used as a bin to store cumulative sum of tableau and k values
    double k1s[maxlength];
    double k2s[maxlength];
    double k3s[maxlength];
    double k4s[maxlength];
    double k5s[maxlength];
    double k6s[maxlength];
    const int numpoints = 64;       
    double to = 0;
    double tf = .5;
    //double dt = static_cast<double>(.5)/static_cast<double>(64);
    double dt = (tf-to)/static_cast<double>(numpoints);
    double mo = 1;
    double concStorage[maxlength][numpoints];   //Stores concs vs. time                     

    //Initialize all the arrays on the host to ensure arrays of 0's are sent to the device.
    //Also, here is where we can seed the system.
    std::cout<<dt;
    std::cout<<"\n";
    concs[0]=mo;
    std::cout<<concs[0];
    std::cout<<" ";
    for (int i=0; i<maxlength; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<numpoints; j++)
            concStorage[i][j]=0;
        concs[i]=0;
        temp[i]=0;
        tempsum[i]=0;
        k1s[i]=0;
        k2s[i]=0;
        k3s[i]=0;
        k4s[i]=0;
        k5s[i]=0;
        k6s[i]=0;
        std::cout<<concs[i];
        std::cout<<" ";
    }
    concs[0]=mo;
    std::cout<<"\n";

    //Define all the pointers to device array memory addresses. These contain the on-GPU
    //addresses of all the data we're generating/using.
    double *d_concs;
    double *d_temp;
    double *d_tempsum;
    double *d_k1s;
    double *d_k2s;
    double *d_k3s;
    double *d_k4s;
    double *d_k5s;
    double *d_k6s;
    double *d_dt;
    int *d_maxlength;
    int *d_numpoints;
    double *d_to;
    double *d_tf;
    double *d_concStorage;

    //Calculate all the sizes of the arrays in order to allocate the proper amount of memory on the GPU.
    size_t size_concs = sizeof(concs);
    size_t size_temp = sizeof(temp);
    size_t size_tempsum = sizeof(tempsum);
    size_t size_ks = sizeof(k1s);
    size_t size_maxlength = sizeof(maxlength);
    size_t size_numpoints = sizeof(numpoints);
    size_t size_dt = sizeof(dt);
    size_t size_to = sizeof(to);
    size_t size_tf = sizeof(tf);
    size_t h_pitch = numpoints*sizeof(double);
    size_t d_pitch;

    //Calculate the "pitch" of the 2D array.  The pitch is basically the length of a 2D array's row.  IT's larger 
    //than the actual row full of data due to hadware issues.  We thusly will use the pitch instead of the data 
    //size to traverse the array.
    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocPitch( (void**)&d_concStorage, &d_pitch, maxlength * sizeof(double), numpoints)); 

    //Allocate memory on the GPU for all the arrrays we're going to use in the integrator.
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_concs, size_concs);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_temp, size_temp);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_tempsum, size_tempsum);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k1s, size_ks);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k2s, size_ks);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k3s, size_ks);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k4s, size_ks);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k5s, size_ks);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_k6s, size_ks);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_maxlength, size_maxlength);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_numpoints, size_numpoints);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_dt, size_dt);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_to, size_to);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_tf, size_tf);

    //Copy all initial values of arrays to GPU.
    cudaMemcpy2D(d_concStorage, d_pitch, concStorage, h_pitch, numpoints*sizeof(double), maxlength, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_concs, &concs, size_concs, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_temp, &temp, size_temp, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_tempsum, &tempsum, size_tempsum, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_k1s, &k1s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_k2s, &k2s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_k3s, &k3s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_k4s, &k4s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_k5s, &k5s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_k6s, &k6s, size_ks, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_maxlength, &maxlength, size_maxlength, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_numpoints, &numpoints, size_numpoints, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_dt, &dt, size_dt, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_to, &to, size_to, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_tf, &tf, size_tf, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Run the integrator.
    rkf5<<<1,1>>>(d_concs, d_concStorage, d_temp, d_tempsum, d_k1s, d_k2s, d_k3s, d_k4s, d_k5s, d_k6s, d_maxlength, d_numpoints, d_pitch, d_dt, d_to, d_tf);
    //gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    //gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //Copy concentrations from GPU to Host.  Almost defunct now that transferring the 2D array works.
    cudaMemcpy(concs, d_concs, size_concs, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    //Copy 2D array of concentrations vs. time from GPU to Host.
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy2D(concStorage, h_pitch, d_concStorage, d_pitch, numpoints*sizeof(double), maxlength, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );   

    //Print concentrations after the integrator kernel runs.  Used to test that data was transferring to and from GPU correctly.
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int i=0; i<maxlength; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<concs[i];
        std::cout<<" ";
    }

    //Print out the concStorage array after the kernel runs.  Used to test that the 2D array transferred correctly from host to GPU and back.
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int i=0; i<maxlength; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<numpoints; j++)
        {
            std::cout<<concStorage[i][j];
            std::cout<<"   ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    cudaDeviceReset();  //Clean up all memory.

    return 0;
}
//Main kernel.  This is mean to be run as a master thread that calls all the other functions and thusly "runs" the integrator.
__global__ void rkf5(double* concs, double* concStorage, double* temp, double* tempsum, double* k1s, double* k2s, double* k3s, double* k4s, double* k5s, double* k6s, int* maxlength, int* numpoints, size_t pitch, double* dt, double* to, double* tf)
{
    /*
    axy variables represent the coefficients in the Butcher's tableau where x represents the order of the step and the y value corresponds to the ky value 
    the coefficient gets multiplied by.  Have to cast them all as doubles, or the ratios evaluate as integers.
    e.g. a21 -> a21 * k1
    e.g. a31 -> a31 * k1 + a32 * k2
    */
    double a21 = static_cast<double>(.25);

    double a31 = static_cast<double>(3)/static_cast<double>(32);
    double a32 = static_cast<double>(9)/static_cast<double>(32);

    double a41 = static_cast<double>(1932)/static_cast<double>(2197);
    double a42 = static_cast<double>(-7200)/static_cast<double>(2197);
    double a43 = static_cast<double>(7296)/static_cast<double>(2197);

    double a51 = static_cast<double>(439)/static_cast<double>(216);
    double a52 = static_cast<double>(-8);
    double a53 = static_cast<double>(3680)/static_cast<double>(513);
    double a54 = static_cast<double>(-845)/static_cast<double>(4104);

    double a61 = static_cast<double>(-8)/static_cast<double>(27);
    double a62 = static_cast<double>(2);
    double a63 = static_cast<double>(-3544)/static_cast<double>(2565);
    double a64 = static_cast<double>(1859)/static_cast<double>(4104);
    double a65 = static_cast<double>(-11)/static_cast<double>(40);

    //for loop that integrates over the specified number of points. Actually, might have to make it a do-while loop for adaptive step sizes 
    for(int k = 0; k < *numpoints; k++)
    {

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, k1s, dt);         //k1 = dt * flux (concs)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize(); //Sync here because kernel continues onto next line before k1 finished

        setup(a21, temp, tempsum, k1s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a21*k1
        arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, temp, tempsum);  //tempsum = concs + a21*k1
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, k2s, dt);       //k2 = dt * flux (concs + a21*k1)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        setup(a31, temp, tempsum, k1s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a31*k1
        setup(a32, temp, tempsum, k2s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a31*k1 + a32*k2
        arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, temp, tempsum);  //tempsum = concs + a31*k1 + a32*k2
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, k3s, dt);           //k3 = dt * flux (concs + a31*k1 + a32*k2)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        setup(a41, temp, tempsum, k1s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a41*k1
        setup(a42, temp, tempsum, k2s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a41*k1 + a42*k2
        setup(a43, temp, tempsum, k3s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a41*k1 + a42*k2 + a43*k3
        arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, temp, tempsum);  //tempsum = concs + a41*k1 + a42*k2 + a43*k3
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, k4s, dt);           //k4 = dt * flux (concs + a41*k1 + a42*k2 + a43*k3)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        setup(a51, temp, tempsum, k1s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a51*k1
        setup(a52, temp, tempsum, k2s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a51*k1 + a52*k2
        setup(a53, temp, tempsum, k3s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a51*k1 + a52*k2 + a53*k3
        setup(a54, temp, tempsum, k4s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a51*k1 + a52*k2 + a53*k3 + a54*k4
        arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, temp, tempsum);  //tempsum = concs + a51*k1 + a52*k2 + a53*k3 + a54*k4
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, k5s, dt);           //k5 = dt * flux (concs + a51*k1 + a52*k2 + a53*k3 + a54*k4)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        setup(a61, temp, tempsum, k1s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a61*k1
        setup(a62, temp, tempsum, k2s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a61*k1 + a62*k2
        setup(a63, temp, tempsum, k3s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a61*k1 + a62*k2 + a63*k3
        setup(a64, temp, tempsum, k4s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a61*k1 + a62*k2 + a63*k3 + a64*k4
        setup(a65, temp, tempsum, k4s, concs, maxlength);   //tempsum = a61*k1 + a62*k2 + a63*k3 + a64*k4 + a65*k5
        arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, temp, tempsum);  //tempsum = concs + a61*k1 + a62*k2 + a63*k3 + a64*k4 + a65*k5
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        calcK<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, k6s, dt);           //k6 = dt * flux (concs + a61*k1 + a62*k2 + a63*k3 + a64*k4 + a65*k5)
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        //At this point, temp and tempsum are maxlength dimension arrays that are able to be used for other things.

        /*
        //All this is is a way of printing all my k values in a 2D array.  No bearing on actual program.
        for (int i = 0; i < *maxlength; i++)
        {
            switch (j)
            {
            case 0: concs[i]=k1s[i];
                break;
            case 1: concs[i]=k2s[i];
                break;
            case 2: concs[i]=k3s[i];
                break;
            case 3: concs[i]=k4s[i];
                break;
            case 4: concs[i]=k5s[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        */
        //calcStepSize
        takeFifthOrderStep<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concs, k1s, k2s, k3s, k4s, k5s, k6s);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        storeConcs<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(concStorage, pitch, k1s, k);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    }
}
//calcStepSize will take in an error tolerance, the current concentrations and the k values and calculate the resulting step size according to the following equation
//e[n+1]=y4[n+1] - y5[n+1]
//__global__ void calcStepSize(double *y5, double* y4)


//takeFourthOrderStep is going to overwrite the old temp array with the new array of concentrations that result from a 4th order step.  This kernel is meant to be launched 
// with as many threads as there are discrete concentrations to be tracked.
__global__ void takeFourthOrderStep(double* concs, double* k1s, double* k2s,double* k3s, double* k4s, double* k5s)
{
    double b41 = static_cast<double>(25)/static_cast<double>(216);
    double b42 = static_cast<double>(0);
    double b43 = static_cast<double>(1408)/static_cast<double>(2565);
    double b44 = static_cast<double>(2197)/static_cast<double>(4104);
    double b45 = static_cast<double>(-1)/static_cast<double>(5);
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    concs[idx] = concs[idx] + b41 * k1s[idx] + b42 * k2s[idx] + b43 * k3s[idx] + b44 * k4s[idx] + b45 * k5s[idx];
}
//takeFifthOrderStep is going to overwrite the old array of concentrations with the new array of concentrations.  As of now, this will be the 5th order step.  Another function can be d
//defined that will take a fourth order step if that is interesting for any reason.  This kernel is meant to be launched with as many threads as there are discrete concentrations
//to be tracked.
//Store b values in register? Constants?
__global__ void takeFifthOrderStep(double* concs, double* k1s, double* k2s,double* k3s, double* k4s, double* k5s, double* k6s)
{
    double b51 = static_cast<double>(16)/static_cast<double>(135);
    double b52 = static_cast<double>(0);
    double b53 = static_cast<double>(6656)/static_cast<double>(12825);
    double b54 = static_cast<double>(28561)/static_cast<double>(56430);
    double b55 = static_cast<double>(-9)/static_cast<double>(50);
    double b56 = static_cast<double>(2)/static_cast<double>(55);
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    concs[idx] = concs[idx] + b51 * k1s[idx] + b52 * k2s[idx] + b53 * k3s[idx] + b54 * k4s[idx] + b55 * k5s[idx] + b56 * k6s[idx];
}
//storeConcs takes the current array of concentrations and stores it in the cId'th column of the 2D concStorage array
//pitch = memory size of a row
__global__ void storeConcs(double* cS, size_t pitch, double* concs, int cId)
{
    int tIdx = threadIdx.x;
    //cS is basically the memory address of the first element of the flattened (1D) 2D array.
    double* row = (double*)((char*)cS + tIdx * pitch);
    row[cId] = concs[tIdx];
}
//Perhaps I can optimize by using shared memory to hold conc values.
__global__ void calcK(double* concs, double* ks, double* dt)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    ks[idx]=(*dt)*flux(idx, concs);
}
//Adds two arrays (a and b) element by element and stores the result in array c.
__global__ void arrAdd(double* a, double* b, double* c)
{                                                 
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    c[idx]=a[idx]+b[idx];
}
//Multiplies two arrays (a and b) element by element and stores the result in array c.
__global__ void arrMult(double* a, double* b, double* c)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    c[idx]=a[idx]*b[idx];
}
//Initializes an array a to double value b.
__global__ void arrInit(double* a, double b)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    a[idx]=b;
}
//Placeholder function for the flux calculation.  It will take the size of the oligomer and current concentrations as inputs.
__device__ double flux(int r, double *concs) 
{
    return -concs[r];
}
//This function multiplies a tableau value by the corresponding k array and adds the result to tempsum.  Used to
//add all the a*k terms.
__device__ void setup(double tableauValue, double *temp, double *tempsum, double *ks, double *concs, int *maxlength) 
{
    //Sets tempsum to tabVal * k
    arrInit<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(temp, tableauValue);       //Set [temp] to tableau value
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    arrMult<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(ks, temp, temp);           //Multiply tableau value by appropriate [k]
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    arrAdd<<< 1, *maxlength >>>(tempsum, temp, tempsum);    //Move tabVal*k to [tempsum]
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

/*
__device__ double knowles_flux(int r, double *conc, double *params)
{

    const double nc = params[0];
    const double ka = params[1];
    //const float kb = params[2];
    //const float kp = params[3];
    const double km = params[4];
    const double kn = params[5];
    //const float n2 = params[6];
    //const float kn2 = params[7];
    const int maxlength = params[8];


    const int r = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    double frag_term = 0;
    double flux = 0;
    if (r == (maxlength-1))
        {
        flux = -km*(r)*conc[r]+2*ka*conc[r-1]*conc[0];
        }
    else if (r > (nc-1))
        {
        for (int s = r+1; s < maxlength; s++)
            {
            frag_term += conc[s];
            }
        //double frag_term = thrust::reduce(conc, conc);
        flux = -km*(r)*conc[r] + 2*km*frag_term - 2*ka*conc[r]*conc[0] + 2*ka*conc[r-1]*conc[0];
        }
    else if (r == (nc-1))
        {
        for (int s = r+1; s < maxlength; s++)
            {
            frag_term += conc[s];
            }
        //double frag_term = thrust::reduce(conc, conc);
        flux = kn*pow(conc[0],nc) + 2*km*frag_term - 2*ka*conc[r]*conc[0];
        }
    else if (r < (nc-1))
        {
        flux[r] = 0;
        }
}
*/

/*
Encountered Errors :
1. nvlink - undefined reference : there's a mismatch between function protoypes and function declaration, possibly the number of arguments. 
"nvlink : error : Undefined reference to '_Z2k1PdS_' in 'x64/Debug/RKF5 Prototype 2.cu.obj'" - fixed by making sure func def had same  parameters as proto

2.1>nvlink : error : Undefined reference to '_Z2k1PdS_' in 'x64/Debug/RKF5 Prototype 2.cu.obj'
1>nvlink : error : Undefined reference to '_Z2k2PdS_' in 'x64/Debug/RKF5 Prototype 2.cu.obj'
1>nvlink : error : Undefined reference to '_Z2k3PdPiS_S_S_S_S_' in 'x64/Debug/RKF5 Prototype 2.cu.obj'
1>nvlink : error : Undefined reference to '_Z2k4PdPiS_S_S_S_S_S_' in 'x64/Debug/RKF5 Prototype 2.cu.obj'
1>nvlink : error : Undefined reference to '_Z2k5PdPiS_S_S_S_S_S_S_' in 'x64/Debug/RKF5 Prototype 2.cu.obj'

This is caused by there being references defined in the prototype that don't exist in the actual function definition.
*/
```

Comment: You need to give a complete example. No there is no special thing related to 64 as far as  I know.

Comment: OK, I put my code in.  The output is a array of all 0's, implying that the kernel was unable to act on the array.  Changing numpoints to 64 makes it integrate.

Comment: Problem in cudaMallocPitch() should be `cudaMallocPitch( (void**)&d_concStorage, &d_pitch, numpoints * sizeof(double), maxlength)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you haven't implemented proper cuda error checking.  Please re-read, study, do whatever you have to do to understand the posting by talonmies.  You need to put the error checking macro after *every* cuda API call, so that means after *each and every* `cudaMalloc`, `cudaMemcpy` etc. you should place this line:

```
gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
```

alternatively, you can simply wrap every call in the error check macro:

```
gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(concs, d_concs, size_concs, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

If you don't do this, yes, the error messages will be confusing, because they will often apply to other (previous) lines of code that threw the error.

Once you do solid error checking, you will discover that the invalid argument is arising from this line of code:

```
cudaMemcpy2D(d_concStorage, d_pitch, concStorage, h_pitch, numpoints*sizeof(double), maxlength, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

To understand why, we need to compare it to the corresponding malloc operation that created the `d_concStorage`, which is this line:

```
gpuErrchk(cudaMallocPitch( (void**)&d_concStorage, &d_pitch, maxlength * sizeof(double), numpoints));
```

Note that in your original variable definitions, `numpoints` is a *width* parameter.  However, in the `cudaMallocPitch` above, you are passing `numpoints` as the last parameter, which is the `height` parameter.   Refer to the cuda API [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g80d689bc903792f906e49be4a0b6d8db).

To make these calls harmonious with each other, we need the height and width parameters to correspond.  I think the correct thing to do is to fix the `cudaMallocPitch` line, to make it match the `cudaMemcpy2D` operation, like so:

```
gpuErrchk(cudaMallocPitch( (void**)&d_concStorage, &d_pitch, numpoints * sizeof(double), maxlength));
```

When I make that change, I can then set `numpoints` to 65 and compile and run your code without any API errors.

Comment: Argh... it's the little things that get you.  Thank you for helping me out with that.  I see what you're saying about the error checking.  I was sloppy with it as I hadn't started using it when I first wrote the program.  Honestly, I didn't even know that I needed to do it because I thought that was something Visual Studio handled.